# Julius acoustic model on cygwin with HTK

Tags: cygwin, speech-recognition, htk

$ HDMan -A -D -T l -m -w wlist -n monophonesl -i -l dlog dict ../lexicon/voxforge_lexicon
C:\cygwin\HTK\htk-3.3-windows-binary\htk\HDMan.exe -A -D -T l -m -w wlist -n monophonesl -i -l dlog dict ../lexicon/voxforge_lexicon

No HTK Configuration Parameters Set

ERROR [+5021]  GetChkedInt: Integer Arg Required for T option
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program C:\cygwin\HTK\htk-3.3-windows-binary\htk\HDMan.exe

I am on the third step to train julius using voxforge training. I created lexicon file and global.ded file as mentioned in the text. wheni run the command on cygwin oi get this error. I have been tring stuff but cannot figure it out. can you help me on this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -T l

The right command includes number 1, not the letter l. Use

> -T 1

To avoid such issues in the future use a font which distinguish them. Copy-paste commands instead of retyping them. Read the message from the tool and try to understand, it already says you where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you i figured it out just 10mins ago. Thank you for your reply, i think from now i will copy paste the commands instead of writing it. I have one more question i have been trying to find a french lexion dictionary. french pronuntiation dictionary to use in julius. If someone can post a link or file.  I tried to find but didnt had the desired results... Thank you again!!

Comment: You can find french phonetic dictionary inside CMUSphinx acoustic models which are working with Pocketsphinx to recognize French. http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/French%20Language%20Model/frenchWords62K.dic/download